# Unity - protect MonoBehaviour-derived classes from instantiating via new in C#

Tags: unity, c#, software-engineering

When the class hierarchy grows and you deal with a lot of custom types in your project, it sometimes becomes hard to remember which types are allowed to be created via `new` and which types are derived from [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) and therefore can't be created via `new` but must instead be attached to the [GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) as a [Component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html).

Is it possible to have some safety-mechanism for this? The goal would be to have two base classes to control the ability to use `new` on a certain type. Ideally resulting in a compile-time error instead of an easy to miss warning in the console (*"You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword. This is not allowed. Blah blah."*).

My attempt to make the constructor protected, like this

```
public class UnCreatableBase : MonoBehaviour {
    protected UnCreatableBase() {
        // using new should be not allowed
    }

    public static T Create<T>() {
        // instead this method allows object creation
        return GameObject.Instantiate (Resources.Load ("Prefabs/" + typeof(T).Name) as GameObject).GetComponent<T>();
    }
}

public class CreatableBase {
    public CreatableBase() {
        // new is ok here
    }
}
```

still allows me to write:

```
var whyDoesThisWork = new UnCreatableBase();
```

I can access the protected constructor even from an outside scope.

Now, the obvious solution would be to make constructors of [MonoBehaviour](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)-derived classes private. Manually. All of them. Manually. I was wondering if there's a way of achieving the same in a more generic way.

Comment: There's no real way to do this that I know of. Generally I name all objects that extend MonoBehaviour as <Something>Component (PlayerComponent for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I lay things out is to have items that exist in the world be Monobehaviours where as supporting processing functionality should be classes. This can further be deliminated by using a C prefix on all processing classes. I.e.

new CCaclualtor();
new CTracking();
new CDateParsing();

GameObject.Instantiate(MyPrefab);

That way, by the type, you know what you should be doing.